# Opening .docx, .pptx etc.. file formats?

Tags: microsoft-office, openoffice

Other than Microsoft Office is there any other Software Package available for Windows that is completely free and can also open .docx, .pptx, .xlsx etc... file formats?

Comment: Use LibreOffice as mentioned below..... the best part is it's free!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two main options are:

1. [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org), previously from Sun/Oracle and now under the wings of the Apache Fundation,
2. and [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org), the main fork from the previous one.

Both are similar and can open the Microsoft Office suite documents with most, but not all unfortunately, functionality and layout preserved.

Other options include:

- [Google Documents](https://docs.google.com/), but your files are then stored online,
- [AbiWord](http://abisource.com/) but only as a text processor (for .docx documents)
- [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) but only as a spreadsheet editor (for .xlsx documents)

Answer (score 3):

You should know that the alternatives have lower document fidelity than the real thing but [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) and OpenOffice are capable of opening such files for quite some time now.

Consider [using open formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_format) and spreading the word.